# Coredata nested relationships retrieving data

Tags: ios, swift, entity-framework, core-data, swift3

I have the following entities:

**Orders <-->> OrderLines <<--> Products**

An Order entity has an '**orderNo**' attribute that has a one to many relationship with an '**orderNo**' attribute in OrderLines. 
The **OrderLines** entity has can have a many to one relationship with the **Products** entity.

[image]

I want to pass a customer code and retrieve  all products that we currently have in the **Products** entity that they have ordered before.

I have tried the following predicate search to no prevail:

```
let pred : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "orderlines.order.customer = %@", customer)
```

I've also tried

```
    let pred : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY orderlines.order.customer = %@", customer)
```

I'm usually faced with an error of:

```
Can not map from a to-many to a to-one relationship
```

Any advice?

**UPDATE**

The code retrieving the data is:

```
 static func repeatsList(customer: String) -> NSArray{
    let ordersRequest : NSFetchRequest<Products> = Products.fetchRequest()
    let pred : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "ANY SELF.line.order.invoicecustomer == %@", customer)
    ordersRequest.predicate=pred
    do{
        let repeatsArray = try GlobalHelpers.getContext().fetch(ordersRequest)
        return repeatsArray as NSArray
    }catch let error as NSError {
        let empty : NSArray = [error]
        return empty
    }
}
```

Comment: try ANY SELF.order.customer ==%@

Comment: unfortunatly that doesn't work either. I have corrected the error now many changing the relationship between Orders and OrderLines to a many to one but now all I get is a zero count when I look at the results

Comment: sorry I missed orderLines it should be

ANY SELF.orderLines.order.customer == %@

Comment: still not working I'm afraid. How do I setup the link between attributes in the relationship?

Comment: In your case surely you can just get all orders where customer == %@ and then reference them via Order.Orders.orderlines ?

Comment: and have you made sure you are puttin '==' and not '=' in your predicates ?

Comment: I've added the code that should return the array of products. And yes I had used '==' but it still returns 0.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141367/discussion-between-richard-thompson-and-seanlintern88).

Comment: The image shows Orders -> OrderLines is a to-one relationship, not to-many.  Might that be affecting your results?